# How to decide the edge direction in graph databases?

Tags: graph-databases, modeling, titan

How does the edge direction impact queries? Is it faster if we query out() than if we query in()? How are the foreign keys stored?

Say, I have two vertices a and b and I create an edge from a to b i.e. a --> b. 
Now if I have the following queries:

1. `g.V(a).out().valueMap()`
2. `g.V(b).in().valueMap()`

Which one will be faster?

I am asking this because I have a scale setup and want to optimize the queries.

Comment: That depends on the system and how the algorithms are implemented. My suggestion is read a book on the topic or provide more detail on your concrete problem to get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 2):

The direction of an edge does not impact performance. What does impact performance is the degree of a node (i.e. the number of incoming vs outgoing edges) as well as the [vertex centric indexing](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/indexes.html#vertex-indexes) defined in the graph DB.

If you worried about performance you should be looking to minimise the number of edges in the direction you most commonly going to be traversing. You should also be looking at adding [vertex centric indices](https://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/indexes.html#vertex-indexes)